# Server response does not display "Request duration"

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I am working with openapi 3.0.0. everything works fine. Eg. generating curl, displayed Response body, Response Headers.

But under the server response "Request duration" is not displayed

refer attached[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have to add `displayRequestDuration: true` inside your `swaggerOptions`,

**displayRequestDuration:** By default Boolean=false. Controls the display of the request duration (in milliseconds) for "Try it out" requests.

**It will look something like this:**

[image]

**Detailed Information > Swagger UI Configurations:**

https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-ui/usage/configuration/

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/blob/master/docs/usage/configuration.md#display