# How to enable response duration in swagger ui JAX-RS

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, swagger-ui

I am working on the JAX-RS project and implemented swagger UI.

Is there a way to enable response time duration?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62476107/175554 does it help ?

Comment: @özkanpakdil thanks for your suggestion. I don't have any swagger configuration file. I have downloaded the Swagger UI source code from git hub and using that. So figuring out how to set up the configuration. I am new to this and still learning